# Creating a PIE chart in a complex table

Tags: google-sheets

Guys can you please help me understand how to create a PIE chart out of these data?

[Table in google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17jpuxGNuwLANF1Fb7cjWkDL_usyfjmI9TVTEWaHSAq4/edit?usp=sharing)

Where RED value is the main sum of all expenses and GREEN values are expense per category. MY goal is to have a monthly overview where money are going by category.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [how-do-i-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I have asked pretty much enough to be clear... Did you open the link? I have marked things that I need to use for a chart. @Aerials

Comment: I did open the sheet. I dont understand it. You should have the minimum necessary, anything else is distracting and cluttering the way to a solution

Comment: I know what you mean. But this is how I want to see the table. Is there a way to use formulas to fetch data on another sheet for building diagrams specifically?  @Aerials

Comment: To answer your comment: Have you looked into Apps Script? Class [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) can be used.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it